# Significance of pV work in enthalpy

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

If we already have $pV$ work included in the internal energy $U = q + w,$ then what is the $pV$ work in the equation for enthalpy $H = E + pV?$

Comment: Who says there's work associated with the enthalpy equation?

Answer (score 2):

The equation is:

$$H = E + pV\tag{1}$$

*Note*: here, $pV$ is product of volume and pressure and not work done.

Differentiate, you will get

$$ΔH = ΔE + ΔpV\tag{2}$$

If pressure is constant, then you will get

$$ΔH = ΔE + p\,ΔV\tag{3}$$

Here, you can write $p\,ΔV$ is work done.

So, you can use the term work done for $pV$ in a special condition only.

Comment: Please give an intuitive sense of Enthalpy.

Comment: Briefly, enthalpy can be called as the total heat content of the system. Positive change in enthaply means process is endothermic i.e it requires heat to he supplied for reaction to happen and negative change means it gives out heat.  You can look out other answers for detailed explanations.